# Rename log file on remote computers if greater than 80MB

Tags: powershell

I am looking to a rename a log file on remote computers once it reaches 80MB. As an example, lets say this is the path "C:\Program Files\Test Folder\TCP.Log" , once it's greater than 80MB, then it should be renamed to TCP1.log. After it's renamed a new log file will be automatically generated by the system with the name "TCP.log" (System will generate it automatically once you rename or delete it). Once the TCP.log reaches 80MB again, then powershell should rename it to TCP2.Log, how can I accomplish this?

I have tried this script, it will rename it to TCP1.Log, but once I run it again, then it will say that the file already exists, so it doesn't rename it to TCP2.LOG .

[image]

Ideally, I would like to create a scheduled task that will run and rename the TCP.log file if it's greater than 80MB on remote machines.

Comment: please, DO NOT POST PICTURES OF CODE. [*frown*] post the text ... otherwise you  are requiring others to type in your code just to try to help you. rather unkind of you, yes? [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a utility function can help in situations like this:

```
function Rename-Unique {
    # Renames a file. If a file with that name already exists,
    # the function will create a unique filename by appending 
    # a sequence number to the name before the extension.
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]$Path
    )
    # Throw a bit nicer error than with [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $Path -PathType Leaf)){
       Throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] "Rename-Unique: The file '$Path' could not be found."
    }

    # split the filename into a basename and an extension variable
    $baseName  = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($Path)
    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($Path)    # this includes the dot
    $folder    = Split-Path -Path $Path -Parent

    # get an array of all filenames (name only) of the files with a similar name already present in the folder
    $allFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter "$baseName*$extension" -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
    # for PowerShell version < 3.0 use this
    # $allFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter "$baseName*$extension" | Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)

    # construct the new filename / strip the path from the file name
    $newName = $baseName + $extension   # or use $newName = Split-Path $newName -Leaf

    if ($allFiles.Count) {
        $count = 1
        while ($allFiles -contains $newName) {
            $newName = "{0}{1}{2}" -f $baseName, $count++, $extension
        }
    }
    Write-Verbose "Renaming '$Path' to '$newName'"
    Rename-Item -Path $Path -NewName $newName -Force
}
```

In your code you can use it like so:

```
$logfile    = 'C:\Program Files\Test Folder\TCP.Log'   # this is your current log file
$maxLogSize = 80MB                                     # the maximum size in bytes you want

# check if the log file exists
if (Test-Path -Path $logfile -PathType Leaf) {
    # check if the logfile is at its maximum size
    if ((Get-Item -Path $logfile).Length -ge $maxLogSize) {
        # rename the current log file using the next sequence number
        Rename-Unique -Path $logfile -Verbose
        # do we need to create the new log file?
        # New-Item -Path $logfile -ItemType 'File' -Force | Out-Null
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the script and it worked :) , all I need to do is either create a scheduled task to run on each computer , or target all computers from a centralized location. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ditto to what Lee_Daily said.

As to your code. You are not really doing any thing to get an increment, so, it's going to give you that same number, hence you error.

Just get the count of the file name, then increment the count by one for the rename. If you are saying the base file name is always the same, then you do even need that loop stuff at all.

Example:

```
# Check for similarly named files
Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\temp\Reports\TCP*'

# Results

    Directory: E:\temp\Reports


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       12/29/2018   1:10 PM             38 TCP.log
-a----       12/29/2018   1:10 PM             38 TCP1.log
-a----        3/14/2019  12:27 PM             45 TCP2.log
-a----       12/29/2018   2:31 PM             34 TCP3.log

# Rename the file that does not have a number with the next highest number of the count of the similarly named file.
Rename-Item -Path E:\Temp\Reports\TCP.log -NewName "TCP$((Get-ChildItem -Path E:\temp\Reports\tcp*).Count).log" -WhatIf

# Results

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: E:\Temp\Reports\TCP.log Destination: E:\Temp\Reports\TCP4.log".
```